# Proving an inequality involving discrete variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functional-inequalities

I'm trying to show that the following inequality holds
$$
\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x^{n+1}}\geq\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-(i+1)})}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-i})},
$$

where $n$ is a positive integer, $x$ and $x_{1}$ are real numbers
satisfying $x_{1}<1$ and $x>x_{1}$.

This is what I have tried: One can show that the left-hand-side
is increasing in $n$, hence to show the above it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}}\geq\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-(i+1)})}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-i})}.
$$
I have tried bounding the terms $(1-x_{1}^{n-(i+1)})$ and $(1-x_{1}^{n-i})$
in the right-hand-side and bring them out of the sum but that doesn't
lead to the desired result.

Comment: you might try multiplying the top and bottom of the RHS by $(1-x)(x_1-x)$, which should get rid of the sums.

Comment: @will I'm not sure how it would get rid of the sums. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The right-hand-side (RHS) has 4 geometric sums. The most tedious is $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^ix_1^{n-i-1}\  =\  x_1^{n-1}(1-x^{n-1}x_1^{1-n})/(1-xx_1^{-1})^{-1}\  =\  \left(x_1^n - x_1x^{n-1}\right)/(x_1-x).\  $ The rest should be similar algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the four geometrical sums in 
$$f_n(x,x_1) = (1-x^n)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-i}) - (1-x^{n+1})\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-(i+1)})$$
and simplifying we obtain

$$f_n(x,x_1) = (x_1x)^n + \frac{g_n(x) - g_n(x_1)}{x-x_1}$$

where $g_n(x) = x^n(1-x)$. From this expression we see that the function $f_n$ is symmetric $f_n(x,x_1)=f_n(x_1,x)$ so the condition $x>x_1$ should not be (and is not) needed.

We will show that $(1-x_1)(1-x)f_n\geq 0$ for all $x,x_1\geq 0$ where the prefactors $(1-x)(1-x_1)$ have been introduced to avoid splitting into different cases for $x>1$ and $x<1$ etc. To do this we use induction on $n$. Assume that for $n\geq 2$ we have  $(1-x_1)(1-x)f_n\geq 0$ then

$$(1-x_1)(1-x)f_{n+1} = (1-x)^2x^n(1-x_1)[1-x_1^{n+1}] + x_1(1-x_1)(1-x)f_n \geq 0$$

For the base case $n=2$ we can factorize $(1-x_1)(1-x)f_2$ as

$$(1-x)f_2 = (1-x)^2(1-x_1)^2\left[x + (1+x)(1+x_1)\right] \geq 0$$

and it follows that the inequality

$$\frac{(1-x)(1-x_1)f_n(x,x_1)}{(1-x)(1-x_1)(1-x^{n+1})\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^i(1-x^{n-i-1})} \geq 0 \implies \frac{1-x^n}{1-x^{n+1}} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-i})}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}x^{i}(1-x_{1}^{n-(i+1)})}$$

holds for all $x,x_1\geq 0$. The range of allowed values can in fact be sharpened to  $x \geq -\frac{1+x_1}{2+x_1}$, $x_1\geq 0$ and by symmetry the inequality also holds for all $x_1\geq -\frac{1+x_1}{2+x_1}$ and $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the identity you used in the induction argument? i.e. $(1-x_1)(1-x)f_{n+1}=(1-x)^2 x^n (1-x_1)(1-x_1^{n+1})+x_1 (1-x_1)(1-x)f_n$ I'm able to verify it but can't figure out how you came up with it. Thanks!

Comment: @V.A. Sure. Without the prefactors we have $f_{n+1} = (xx_1)^{n+1} + \frac{g_{n+1}(x)-g_{n+1}(x_1)}{x-x_1}$. First I write the last factor as $g_{n+1}(x) = x g_n(x)$ and $g_{n+1}(x_1)=x_1g_n(x_1)$ and then I factor the first term as $xg_n(x) = (x-x_1)g_n(x) + x_1 g_n(x)$ (adding and subtracting). This gives us $f_{n+1} = (xx_1)^{n+1} + g_n(x) + x_1\frac{g_n(x)-g_n(x_1)}{x-x_1}$. Now using the defintion of $f_n$ gives us $f_{n+1} = (xx_1)^{n+1} + g_n(x) + x_1[f_n - (xx_1)^n]$. Finally writing out $g_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$ and factorizing gives us the result. Let me know if something is not clear.